# Using php to insert data into a css file

Tags: php, html

Hello, I Was wondering if there was a way to use php to call on a css file and insert data into it. The purpose would be to to allow a user to easily modify a css file instead of having to go into the file manually. It would be a field called Width: with a text area for them to enter it in.

Comment: It's just a text file, there's nothing stopping PHP from reading and writing it, as long as it has permissions.

Comment: You can also have your CSS URL point to a PHP script, and it can output the CSS, just like it usually outputs HTML.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at this?  A Google search for something like "PHP write to file" can probably get you started.

Comment: ok sorry i forgot people will just - the crap out of your stuff it your not too specific I fixed it by using ' instead of " i like toms and youns answer:)

Answer (score 5):

Sure. You can easily read a file with `file_get_contents` and then write it back to the file with `file_put_contents`.

```
// load the css file into a string
$css = file_get_contents("my.css");

// make changes, e.g....
$css = str_replace("width: 10px;", "width: 20px;", css);

// save those changes
file_put_contents("my.css", $css);
```

Comment: Whoops, thanks for fixing that @YounElan!

Comment: lol, with pleasure... I have done that a few times too :)

Answer (score 0):

Create an script to "generate special css" using functions like fwrite() that will create an special css for each user and then load it if user is logged to overwrite the original css